# How to fix No overload for 'Main_Navigated' matches delegate 'NavigatedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am encountering the following error:

> Error CS0123   No overload for 'Main_Navigated' matches delegate 'NavigatedEventHandler

Here is my code.  The error is occurring on **line 10**.

```
<Window x:Class="The_App_for_students.MainWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:The_App_for_students"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="Main" Margin="0,0,0,0" Navigated="Main_Navigated"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Welcome!  I have updated your question to better explain the problems you are encountering.  Good luck!

Comment: @Wafeelka: Do you have an event handler defined in the code-behind? Do you need one? Othwerwise you should simply remove `Navigated="Main_Navigated` from your XAML markup.

Answer (score 1):

`MainWindow1.Main_Navigated` needs to look like [NavigatedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigatedeventhandler?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
public void Main_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {}
```